# Wordpress - update/publish a post with client side API call

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, timing

Here is what I need...

1. In backend of WP, user hits either update or publish to save post
2. Before post is saved, client side js (has to be js) calls a web API for some data
3. API async call returns data
4. Data is stored in custom field
5. Post is then saved

I've got all the pieces, just not sure how to make timing work...what WP event to hook into, how to stop post update, how to wait for response from API, then restart post update.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the save_post hook. There  to make the Api call and then use the update_post_meta function to fill the Custom field?

Comment: There are restrictions with this API on making calls from the server (using PHP) so I have to make the call in JS in the browser.  I can use that hook and call the API via JS but then since it is asynchronous the post saves before the data is returned.

Comment: The `save_post` events fires when the post is allready saved. So wait for your asynchronus JS and in the success callback send another ajax to update the custom field with your infos. You just need the post id.

Comment: Thanks JP...  So I am enqueueing the admin script if post-new.php or post.php.  But when I try and call the javascript function from save_post like this [?><script>myFunction()</script><?php], I'm getting the "The response is not a valid JSON response." error.  Show in rest is true for this post type. ...keep hitting error trying to do this.  Ugh!